# How to create a local account from an external private key in Web3.py?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapps, web3.py

I've been using `local_account = w3.eth.account.create(keys['private_key_1'])` to create a local account offline. When I check the public key returned from `local_account.address` it does not match the existing public key. What should I do?

P.S. The key returned is a string & I've tried changing the private key format from "0x12345" to "12345". I think [this](https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eth_account.html#eth_account.account.Account) is a solution but I can't figure out how to instantiate the class and call the from_key method.

Answer (score 8):

That's because the attribute of the function [`w3.eth.account.create(...)`](https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eth_account.html#eth_account.account.Account.create) is not the private key.

To generate an account from an external private key you must use the function [`w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(...)`](https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eth_account.html#eth_account.account.Account.privateKeyToAccount).

Example:

```
>>> private_key = "f8f8a2f43c8376ccb0871305060d7b27b0554d2cc72bccf41b2705608452f315"
>>> acct = w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(private_key)
>>> acct.address
'0x001d3F1ef827552Ae1114027BD3ECF1f086bA0F9'
```

`privateKeyToAccount` will be deprecated for version 0.5 and replaced by [`w3.eth.account.from_key(...)`](https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eth_account.html#eth_account.account.Account.from_key).

Example:

```
>>> private_key = 0xf8f8a2f43c8376ccb0871305060d7b27b0554d2cc72bccf41b2705608452f315
>>> acct = Account.from_key(private_key)
>>> acct.address
'0x001d3F1ef827552Ae1114027BD3ECF1f086bA0F9'
```

Comment: Thanks. Can this new account be used as the default account in order to sign and send transactions?

Comment: You can set the default account doing `w3.eth.defaultAccount = acct` where `acct` is the account created previously. Check `w3.eth.defaultAccount.address`.

Comment: I'm getting the same error as in this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97912/typeerror-address-eth-account-signers-local-localaccount-object-at-0x7fc0780ad when trying to run `.transact()` on a contract when setting  `w3.eth.default_account = Account.from_key(private_key)`. Look like it's expecting a string.

Comment: @shellwhale You are giving an object as an argument, you should pass `acct.address` since it is the address as a string.

Comment: If we are only passing the public address as a string, how could web3.py ever access the external private key? Because doing `w3.eth.default_account = acct.address` gives out a 'unknown account' when running `.transact()`.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you should write `transact({'from': acct.address})` instead of `transact({'from': acct})`.

Comment: I just tried that and it failed with the same 'unknown account' error.  Please see https://gist.github.com/shellwhale/fe66a460e64cb7d257e2a4186cc82f0b

Comment: @shellwhale I tested your code and it works perfectly. If you didn't resolve the problem, I suggest you open a new question ;).

Comment: @alberto That's weird, which version of web3.py are you currently running?

Comment: @shellwhale Check your gist link to avoid more comments here ;).