# TypeError: Address <eth_account.signers.local.LocalAccount object at 0x7fc0780ad040> must be provided as a string [web3.py]

Tags: web3.py

I am trying to call a function using web3.py. I am looking to call `transact` on a funciton call using my account, however I'm running into some issues.

```py
from web3 import Web3
from eth_account import Account

acct = Account.from_key(PRIVATE_KEY_HERE)
erc20 = w3.eth.contract(address=erc20_address, abi=erc20_abi)
erc20.functions.approve(spender, amount).transact({'from': acct})
```

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Address <eth_account.signers.local.LocalAccount object at 0x7fc0780ad040> must be provided as a string
```

[It looks like this person had the same error](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/1714).

Comment: Have you found a solution for your issue?

Comment: Yes. You need to use the address. See the below answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be `.transact({'from': acct.address})` instead of `.transact({'from':acct})`.

the `'from'` key needs to take a string, and `Account` from `eth-account` is a dictionary. `Account.address` should return the address as a string.